# Color Switch Unity 2D game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am learning Color Switch Unity 2D game. When my player touches any color of obstacles, it dies. Although it hits the same color of obstacles, game is over. Player should not be dies. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: Can you please show us the code that you are using to decide the is the player going to die or continue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class Obstacles : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    private Player player;
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Player>();     
    }
  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target)
    {
        if (player.activeColor != this.tag)
        {
            player.GameOver();
        }
    }
}
```

With class OnTriggerEnter2D,  my player dies even though it touches with the same color of obstacles. Without it, the player continues even it touches the obstacles.

P.S.: it seems so easy to fix it up. But I am a beginner in Unity.